How to convert register value from sql script output to json object
I am new to ansible, i have a sal file which on execution gives a result looks like below :
Msg: |- 

    zdf02ahg04.adf.corp.domain.com 
    /home/eof/goto/tfe 
    
    zdf03ahg04.adf.corp.domain.com 
    /home/eof/goto4/tfe 

I am trying to pass this value to to_json filter and I get something like this -
msg: |-
  '"[''zdf02ahg04.adf.corp.domain.com'', ''/home/eof/goto/tfe'', '''', ''zdf03ahg04.adf.corp.domain.com'', ''/home/eof/goto4/tfe'']"'

But i want to get something like this
msg:
 - HOSTNAME: zdf02ahg04.adf.corp.domain.com
   Path: /home/eof/goto/tfe
 - HOSTNAME: zdf03ahg04.adf.corp.domain.com
   Path: /home/eof/goto4/tfe

Please help and thank you in advance.
I have tried to do
- set_fact: 
    my_var: "{{ sql.stdout_lines | to_json }}" 

- debug: 
    msg: "{{ my_var }}"


For example, given the file for testing
shell> cat test.txt 

zdf02ahg04.adf.corp.domain.com 
/home/eof/goto/tfe 

zdf03ahg04.adf.corp.domain.com 
/home/eof/goto4/tfe

Read it
    - command: cat test.txt
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

gives
  out.stdout: |2-
  
    zdf02ahg04.adf.corp.domain.com
    /home/eof/goto/tfe
  
    zdf03ahg04.adf.corp.domain.com
    /home/eof/goto4/tfe

Split and select non-empty lines. Use the filter batch and create sublists. Then, use the filter community.general.dict and create the list of dictionaries
  my_var: "{{ out.stdout | split('\n') | select | batch(2) |
              map('zip', ['HOSTNAME', 'Path']) |
              map('map', 'reverse') |
              map('community.general.dict') }}"

gives what you want
  my_var:
  - HOSTNAME: zdf02ahg04.adf.corp.domain.com
    Path: /home/eof/goto/tfe
  - HOSTNAME: zdf03ahg04.adf.corp.domain.com
    Path: /home/eof/goto4/tfe



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_var: "{{ out.stdout | split('\n') | select | batch(2) |
                map('zip', ['HOSTNAME', 'Path']) |
                map('map', 'reverse') |
                map('community.general.dict') }}"

  tasks:

    - command: cat test.txt
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

    - debug:
        var: my_var

You can omit the filter split if the attribute stdout_lines is available
    my_var: "{{ out.stdout_lines | select | batch(2) |
                map('zip', ['HOSTNAME', 'Path']) |
                map('map', 'reverse') |
                map('community.general.dict') }}"



Hi @vladimir Botka,
I have done what you said, but im getting the following when printing
"

Find out which filter fails. Start with out.stdout_lines | select and proceed by adding filters out.stdout_lines | select | batch(2) ... until you find out what was wrong.
